# How to dynamically add synthetic craters in a real image

Tags: python, node-editor

I am very new to blender, however, I would like to generate a synthetic data set for my project. The idea is to add synthetic craters to satellite images. My starting point for this was this [**youtube tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7OpmpE8xTc).

Now I have essentially two questions, first, when I add **one crater** to an image (see image 1) it is **not transparent** and somewhat the way I want it to be (except for the crater color which isn't the brown I set it to be (in the Principled BSDF)), however, if I add **multiple craters** (see image 2) they start to get **transparent** for some reason. **Why is that the case and how do I fix it?**

The second question would be about the automation. **Is it possible to dynamically add a different amount of craters?** Right now I would add always four craters, however, I would like to be able to change this amount in a python script so that I can generate images without my interaction.

Thanks.

[image: Two images of synthetic craters, one transparent and not]

Blender File Link:
[image]